# Trying out a simple List example on Sencha Touch 2, I get "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying out Sencha 2, I can get a nested list to display correctly taking an example from the tutorials, but as soon as I try a simple list variant I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #Object

I'm using the exact same code as in the example, with just a change to fit the code in its own file:

```
Ext.define('layouts.view.TheList', {
  extend: 'Ext.List',
  xtype: 'thelist',

  config: {
    title: 'The List',

    store: {
      fields: ['name'],
      data: [
        {name: 'Cowper'},
        {name: 'Everett'},
        {name: 'University'},
        {name: 'Forest'}
      ]
    },

    itemTpl: '{name}'

  }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error. It worked properly when i added the following code

```
requires: [
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.data.Store',
],
```

before the 'config:' block.

Comment: Had the same problem, and this resolved it.  I am very surprised that the walk-through video doesn't tell you to do this, the big problem being, it's exactly us newbies that will have no idea what to do when something like this is wrong with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing issues with some of my lists, only displaying the content if I set a height value, I don't know what causes this problem yet.

```
Ext.define('ZF.view.wall.Foo', {
  extend: 'Ext.List',
  xtype: 'thelist',

  config: {
   title: 'The List',
   height: 600,

  store: {
   fields: ['name'],
   data: [
    {name: 'Cowper'},
    {name: 'Everett'},
    {name: 'University'},
    {name: 'Forest'}
   ]
  },

itemTpl: '{name}'
}
});
```

Comment: Have you figured out the problem?

Comment: I'm using flex property set to value 1 in the list and the render the list inside VBox layout

Comment: I've fixed it by using layout `fixed`